query optimization for perfex crm accounting module when dealing with large number of data
Could someone assist me in optimizing the following two functions responsible for loading data into dashboard charts? They currently take approximately five minutes to execute due to a growing dataset of over 150,000 rows. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.
$where_payment = $this->get_where_report_period(db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.date');
        $this->db->select_sum('amount');
        if($where_payment != ''){
            $this->db->where($where_payment);
        }
        $this->db->where('((select count(*) from ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history where ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history.rel_id = ' . db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.id and ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history.rel_type = "payment") = 0) and currency = '.$data_currency);
        $this->db->join(db_prefix() . 'invoices', db_prefix() . 'invoices.id=' . db_prefix() . 'invoicepaymentrecords.invoiceid', 'left');
        $payment = $this->db->get(db_prefix().'invoicepaymentrecords')->row();

second is below
$this->db->select_sum('total');
        if($where != ''){
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $this->db->where('((select count(*) from ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history where ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history.rel_id = ' . db_prefix() . 'invoices.id and ' . db_prefix() . 'acc_account_history.rel_type = "invoice") = 0) and currency = '.$data_currency);
        $invoice = $this->db->get(db_prefix().'invoices')->row();

database schema is below


I don't think you're going to get an answer because you didn't add the database schema with the relevant tables to your question. Have you indexed your database correctly? Also, you're using a lot of functions/methods which obscure what they do, are they all part of CodeIgniter?

thanks for reply i added database schema also if you need additional info please let me know thanks @KIKOSoftware other function are not related to database query they are just getting loged in company data thanks

If you want to optimize a query, you should post SQL.

also these functions are working perfectly just need to optimize them thanks

i have edited make it more clear can you pelase check @Olivier

Please include the query you are executing in SQL form.


Perfex CRM is a commercial software. Modifying its code can have contractual consequences. Not to mention that future upgrades or patches released by the Perfex CRM will not run because of the changes. It is also possible that optimising this query may interfere with other features of the software. I would ask their official support for help first. 2) If you still want to go forward here, then please get the sql version of the query and share it with us along with an output of the explain of the query.



Perfex CRM markets itself as suitable for small businesses and individual professionals. If you have 150k rows in a table, you may simply have outgrown this software.

